# What does depenendcies mean in an npm module?

Tags: node.js, npm, module, dependencies, node-modules

What does dependencies mean in an npm module?

For example in [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel?) there are [4 dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel?activeTab=dependencies).

Does it mean that if I install this module the dependecies will be installed too?

Also, if for example a package has [expressJS](https://expressjs.com/) as a dependency and it is running on [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) (serverless functions) how will it work? Will it have to install express to the serverless app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the dependencies of localtunnel are also installed when you install this package. As you can observe, these dependencies, like axios for example, also have their own dependencies, which will also be installed and so on…

To better understand what's going on you can try the following on your machine in an empty throwaway directory:

```bash
mkdir throwaway && cd throwaway
npm install localtunnel
```

After a few seconds, inspects the content of this dir. A `node_modules` directory is now present and contains the full flatten representation of `localtunnel` and its dependencies tree. Npm is smart enough to optimize identical dependencies (if any) and move them higher in the directories tree.